# How to setup cron for updating membership statuses in cPanel

Tags: cron-job

How do I setup cron (via cPanel) to execute, specifically membership statuses? I.e. I know how to get to cPanel's cron management, but not sure how I tell that cron management tool to execute the membership status cron as setup inside of drupal.  An example for doing that (and to run all of them) would be nice. :-)

I've read the CiviCRM manual for membership status AND watched the cPanel video, but really need an example for doing specifically the above, and with that information I think I can construct all the others I need.

Using CiviCRM 4.7.13, Drupal 7.51

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 2):

I've expanded Kainuk's SOLUTION here (thanks Kainuk!):  To start executing civicrm jobs without doing them one-time-only as done with Sheduled Jobs List (Civicrm > Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs), then its easiest just to install drupal's module, [civicrm_cron](http://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron) and it will automatically start executing the jobs on your scheduled jobs list. This is much easier than doing this at the command line or inside of cPanel. For even finer grain control of your scheduled jobs, you can use [elysia cron](http://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron).

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression from the cPanel documentation that cPanel is able to run a php script on a scheduled time. Using this you can execute all scheduled jobs from CiviCRM with the php command line interface as documented in [PHP cli method](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod). On the same page you can find a lot other scheduling mechanisms like calling an url.

And if you got the drupal cron working you can build on this success by using the Drupal module [CiviCRM Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cron).

Comment: cli method does not work with cPanel. I tried numerous other was, but no cigar. HOWEVER! Drupal's module, civicrm_cron was perfect! In fact it was way to easy! Thanks for your help! - Carl